# how to get the object name from json call

Tags: javascript, json

So i have my json coming back looking like this:

```
  "full_secnames": {
    "STALLS": "Stalls",
    "CIRCLE": "Circle",
    "P3": "Price Level 3",
    "P2": "Price Level 2",
    "P1": "Price Level 1"
  },
```

Now i don't know what its gonna come back as `"STALLS"` or `"CIRCLE"`, Now i thought it would something along the lines of this

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.full_secnames.length; i++) {
```

When i do this nothing happens. (no length perhaps via the debugger)

How go about getting the main name of these?

Sam

Comment: JS objects do not have a `.length`. You should instead iterate on the object keys: `Object.keys(json.full_secnames).forEach(function(i) {...})`.

Comment: "You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means." [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).